# Concatenate Two columns data into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Concatenate DesireMinSalary and DesireMaxSalary columns data into new column namely ConcateSalary and remove currency symbol,decimal points from Answer Column and then compare the values With ConcateSalary  if same then reurn true else false

```
select  UserID_FK, DesireMinSalary,DesireMaxSalary,Answer,
case when answer = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DesireMinSalary)  then 'True'else 'False' end as reslut
from TAL_TBL_Candidate
 inner join tal_tbl_users
 on Userid = UserID_FK
  inner join [AocJobs_Migration].[dbo].[AoCJobsJobseekerProfiles]
 on email = susername
 WHERE ProfileQuestion='What is your desired annual salary?'
```

Current output:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| UserID_FK | DesireMinSalary | DesireMaxSalary | Answer            | result |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| 823       | 20000           | 24999           | £20,000 - £24,999 | true   |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
| 557       | 12300           | 85000           | £30,000 - £40,000 |false   |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+--------+
| UserID_FK | DesireMinSalary | DesireMaxSalary | ConcatSalrye | Answer            | result |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+--------+
| 823       | 20000           | 24999           | 20000-24999  | £20,000 - £24,999 | true   |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+--------+
| 557       | 12300           | 85000           | 12300-85000  | £30,000 - £40,000 | false  |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Use [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  on `[answer]` or [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on `[DesireMinSalary]` and `[DesireMaxSalary]`? What have you tried?

Comment: I  need to compare concated salry and answer if both have same values then return true else false

Comment: The only difference between your current output, and the expected is the addition of the column `ConcatSalrye`; and all you need for that is what to either use `REPLACE`, or `CONCAT` as above.

Comment: it seems the real problem here, however, is that you are storing what is clearly numerical range values as a `varchar` (if you want to compare). `Answer` should be 2 columns, one with a the min value, and one  with the max, and should be a numerical data type. Fix your design, and the problem you have goes away, as it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this. As you said your current output is already coming, then only need to add a column by combining 2 column values.

```
select  UserID_FK, DesireMinSalary,DesireMaxSalary, (cast(DesireMinSalary as varchar(15)) + '-' + cast(DesireMaxSalary as varchar(15)) as  ConcatSalrye ,   Answer,
case when answer = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DesireMinSalary)  then 'True'else 'False' end as reslut
from TAL_TBL_Candidate
 inner join tal_tbl_users
 on Userid = UserID_FK
  inner join [AocJobs_Migration].[dbo].[AoCJobsJobseekerProfiles]
 on email = susername
 WHERE ProfileQuestion='What is your desired annual salary?'
```

Comment: While comparing Answer With concatsalrye-> answer = CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), ConcatSalrye  ) its giving invalid column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some STRING to INT conversion to check MIN and MAX salary from Answer with column 'DesireMinSalary' & 'DesireMaxSalary' as below-

```
SELECT
..... 
CASE
    WHEN CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Answer,2,CHARINDEX(' - ',Answer,0)-2),',','') AS INT) = CAST(DesireMinSalary AS INT)
        AND CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Answer,(CHARINDEX(' - ',Answer,0))+4,LEN(Answer)),',','') AS INT) = CAST(DesireMaxSalary AS INT) 
        THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
END AS reslut
....
```